# recursive function could not find the node and returns null

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, treeview

I have the following `treeview`:

```
-node1 //ID=1
    -node1.1 //ID=1/1
    -node1.2
-node2
    -node2.1
        -node2.1.1 //ID = 2/1/1
    -node2.2
    -node2.3
-node3
    -node3.1
        -node3.1.1
        -node3.1.2 //ID = 3/1/2
    -node3.2
        -node3.2.1
```

The `"ID"` which I am using are exactly the order of the child and it is already in the `Tag` of node. For example I want to look for the node `-node3.1.2` and I am using the node with `itemId = "3/1/2"` which I have passed it via `Tag`.

Here is my code:

```
public TreeNode FromID(string itemId, TreeNode rootNode)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in rootNode.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Tag != null)
        {
            var value = node.Tag as NodeTag;
            string Node_ID = value.NodeID;
            if (Node_ID.Equals(itemId)) return node;
            TreeNode next = FromID(itemId, node);
            if (next != null) return next;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I am running the code then it has always `null` as output. I am confused why I have it? May I ask your helps?

Comment: Have you tried debugging through the code? Then you can see what acutally happens.

Comment: @tahatmat, yap, I have done it. but it could not find the `node`.

Comment: What value do you get if if you do "int c = string.Compare(itemId, Node_ID);"?  If this is not returning 0, then your strings are somehow different and you need to look into the values of them and see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many time testing I found the right answer. Thanks for your comments which helped me a lot. Because it failed when the IF was not true, then I added else part as well and found out to be correct.

```
.....
else
{
    TreeNode nodeChild = FindTn(node.Nodes, NodeID);
    if (nodeChild != null) return nodeChild;
}
```